# udevd is using a lot of CPU

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, service

We have an Amazon instance that runs on Amazon Linux as its operating system. We have recently noticed that the process `udevd` takes a lot of CPU as in it constantly takes more than 90% of the CPU.

I have seen in some places people advising restarting the `systemd` service in order to fix this issue or restart the `udev` service. But Amazon Linux does not have the commands I am used to in Ubuntu to manage services.

I would like to know how I can restart any of those services and will restarting any of those services result in a server downtime.

UPDATE 1:

I tried `sudo /sbin/udevd restart` and it gave me this error

`error binding udev control socket`

UPDATE 2:
Tried using commands from this post https://askubuntu.com/q/82470/150488, didn't help either